# IIS create subdirectories to root folder and detect which subdirectory user coming from

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to have a website **www.mywebsite.com** & seperate sub directories like **www.mywebsite.com/uk** , **www.mywebsite.com/us** etc...

So **www.mywebsite.com/uk** will show UK related contents. Similarly **www.mywebsite.com/us** will show US related contents. My Database & project files are all one. I would not want to maintain seperate files for each folders which is the worst case scenario.

Is there a way i can create Sub directories like 'UK','US' and have those point to the $root folder instead of redirection. Also from the code i should be able to detect from which subdirectory the user is coming from.

I hope my question is clear. i can provide more details if the question ain't clear/

Comment: Did you try to use url rewrite to make requets to `/uk/*` actually go to `/*?locale=en-GB`

Comment: Well in fact that would be one ideal solution. But i was thinking out loud to perform this using Virtual directories...

Comment: So you can publish one source code under two different directories. I'd avoid that until you have enough resources to support and maintain such solution, or there will be a lot of code difference. But again from many perspectives it's easier to have just 1 site.

Comment: Yes i want to have only one site. All my files will be under the root folder. I want to create sub directories under the root eg: $root/uk which infact points to the $root itself. So no code replication.

So my question highlights whether this is possible and also from the code i should be able to detect which subdirectory the user is accessing from.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look to me to be a right way. Anyway [try to examine](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ghCEoZ) `Request.Url`, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx).

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://example.com/uk/Foo.aspx?Bar";

string a = url.AbsolutePath; // /uk/Foo.aspx
string q = url.PathAndQuery; // /uk/Foo.aspx?Bar
```